# Get integer out of an IV* in Perl

Tags: c, perl

Is there a macro or function in the Perl API for getting the actual integer field of a `IV*`? I can find tons of information for getting at just about every other kind of value in `perlguts` and `perlapi` but this one seems to elude me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [perlguts](http://p3rl.org/guts) `SvIV(SV*)` should do the trick.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Inline C => <<'END';
void print_iv (SV* input) {
  if (! SvIOK(input))
    croak("Not an integer");
  printf("Printing integer %d\n", SvIV(input));
}
END

print_iv(3);
```

Comment: Doesn't that return the `*IV`, not the actual integer?

Comment: If it `printf`s with the `%d` format isn't that it? I'm not sure how else to check.

Comment: nm - I guess it does work. I confused myself, as usual. :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: The confusing bit is that `perlapi` shows the following signature for `SvIV`: `IV SvIV(SV* sv)` - though I'm not sure what `IV` is supposed to mean without the `*`. Maybe I should actually look in the headers.

Comment: I think IV is just a typedef IIRC, not an object.

Comment: `SvIOK` is not appropriate there. `SvIV` can and should be called unconditionally. You also forgot to do `mg_get(input)` in case the variable is magical.

Comment: @friedo, C doesn't have objects. `IV` is a signed integer type large enough to hold an integer and a pointer.

Comment: Oh and `%d` is for `int`, which `IV` might not be, so that's wrong too.

Comment: @friedo btw, before you were confusing `SvIV` with `newSViv` I think.

Comment: (and if you can make any sense of the capitalization in XS you're a better man than I am).

Answer (score 3):

```
use Inline C => <<'__EOC__';

   void print_iv(SV* input) {
      SvGETMAGIC(input);
      printf("Printing integer %"IVdf"\n", SvIV(input));
   }

__EOC__

print_iv(3);
```

This fixes three errors in the previous answer:

- You need to call `SvGETMAGIC` before accessing a scalar in case it's magical (a special variable).
- `SvIOK` shouldn't be checked. How a number is stored is of no consequence.
- `%d` is not always appropriate for `IV`. Not using the correct pattern can lead to a segfault.